# HTML, Javascript: check and get data from an input copy-pasted table

Tags: javascript, html-table, extract

I am building a website that can copy-paste table from MS.Excel or MS.Word into a text area.

```
15.00 1.35 3.58  
12.0s5o9 123.56 5.15
```

I want to get value from each cell with Id. Ex: Id11 = 15.00, Id12 = 1.35, Id21 = 12.0s5o9 ...
Then check the number if it contain letter, then highlight that cell. Ex: Id21 = 12.0s5o9 that should be highlighted.

After trying some codes by myself, I changed to try using 'tinymce' texteditor as below.
HTML code I wrote:

```
<form id="converted_form">
<textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script language="javascript" src="check.js"></script>
```

In Javascript I wrote:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn"); 
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){ var content = 
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
```

What I got is:

```
<table border="0" width="156" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><colgroup><col width="72" /> <col width="49" /> <col width="35" /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="right" width="72" height="20">15</td>
<td align="right" width="49">1.35</td>
<td align="right" width="35">3.58</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12.0s5o9</td>
<td align="right">123.56</td>
<td align="right">5.15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This does not contain Id of each cell for me to check and highlight the cell that contain letter.
Can anyone share idea to get cell value and Id; or other way beside tinymce?

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. We'll do what we can to help you with any problems you face but questions like this, where you're essentially asking for all the code and can't show what you've done so far, don't generally get good responses.

Comment: The good idea is to write a code.

Comment: Actually, I have tried some codes, and later on I found texteditor "tinyMCE" and when I get content of each cell with code (tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()); it gives an html code without id of each cell, so that I cannot process each cell data. That's why I return to a code for this, if you could share.I am sorry for my naive post.

Comment: Please provide more information. Include what you have tried with tinyMCE. Also please give an example of what you are pasting into the editor, the HTML that is output and an example of what you want to achive

Comment: I have a copy-paste table from excel:  15.00 1.35 3.58  12.0s5o9 123.56 5.15  and I want to highlight the cell that contain letter (ex: cell 2,1).  HTML code of tinymce that I wrote:    <form id="converted_form">    <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" /> </form>    <script language="javascript" src="check.js"></script>

Comment: Java that I wrote:    var btn = document.getElementById("btn"); 
   btn.addEventListener("click",function(){    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()

Comment: What I got is:    <table border="0" width="156" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><colgroup><col width="72" /> <col width="49" /> <col width="35" /></colgroup>    <tbody>    <tr>    <td align="right" width="72" height="20">15</td>    <td align="right" width="49">1.35</td>    <td align="right" width="35">3.58</td>    </tr>    <tr>    <td height="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12.0s5o9</td>    <td align="right">123.56</td>
<td align="right">5.15</td>    </tr>    </tbody>    </table>

Comment: Please use the [edit feature](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52807983/edit) to edit in the new information. Comments can be temporary, besides code is a little hard to read in the comments. When edditing the code in make sure to format it. The '{}' button in the editor marks the selection as code.

Comment: @Jon P: Thanks. I edited my post already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have an id as such as that info does not come across from the paste. We can work with the table you get from tinyMCE though.

Your requirements are not exactly clear, but the following should get you moving in the right direction

```js
//From tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
var tableString ='<table border="0" width="156" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><colgroup><col width="72" /> <col width="49" /> <col width="35" /></colgroup><tbody><tr><td align="right" width="72" height="20">15</td><td align="right" width="49">1.35</td><td align="right" width="35">3.58</td></tr><tr><td height="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12.0s5o9</td><td align="right">123.56</td><td align="right">5.15</td></tr></tbody></table>';

//we could add the table straight to the DOM, but as
//we aren't sure as to what you wnat to do lets create a 
//"virtual" DOM node
var dv = document.createElement('div');

//Add Table string to out holder node
dv.innerHTML = tableString;

//Get the actual table
var tableDOM = dv.firstChild; 

//get table cells
var tds = tableDOM.querySelectorAll("td");
var total = 0.0;

//Loop through the cells.
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
{
  var val = tds[i].innerText.trim();
  //numeric check
  if(isNaN(val) || isNaN(parseFloat(val)))  {
    //Highlite non numeric cell -you could add a class here instead
    tds[i].style.color = "#F00";
  }else{
    //Add numeric cells to total
    total += parseFloat(val);
  }
}
//Log the toal
console.log(total);

//Add the Table to the visible DOM
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(tableDOM);

//Or if you want to replace the contents of your editor:
//tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(tableDOM.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @WCh glad to help, if this is your accepted answer, please click the check mark and consider an up vote by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 3 by 3 table which checks if each input has the letter `e`. If every cell has the letter `e`, it alerts the words "Common Letter!", which you can replace with whatever you want.

```js
var checked = [];

function check(elem) {
    var elemArr = elem.value.split("");
    if (elemArr.includes("e") {
        if (!(checked.includes(elem.id))) {
            checked.push(elem.id);
        }
    }
    if (checked.length >= 9) {
        //Do your thing here
        alert("Common Letter!");
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input-1-1" type="text" oninput="check(this")/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-1-2" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-1-3" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input-2-1" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-2-2" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-2-3" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="input-3-1" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-3-2" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="input-3-3" type="text" oninput="check(this") />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code of checking. Before that, I want to extract data in each cell with cell Id in Javascript, and  am stuck with it.

Comment: @WCh so you just want to make a table with the data from each cell?

Comment: yes. I want to have a text area to post table, and get the cell value with cell id. So that I can process the value and put it back to the table.

Comment: @WCh Can you provide a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: as my post was hard to understand, I edited my post already. Please refer to my post again.

Answer (score 0):

## Access `<td>`

If I understood correctly your objective is to highlight any `<td>` that has any letters within its content. There are 3 functions in the following demo:

> **processTable(String or Object of `<table>`)**

- Assigns an `#id` to each `<tr>` with this pattern **"row"`+increment_of_row`**
- Assigns an `#id` to each `<td>` with this pattern **"cel"`+increment_of_row`+'-'`+incrment_of_cell`**
- Checks each of the `<td>s'` content and should it find a letter, it will highlight the background of that `<td>` gold. It determines if content is a number by using the second function:

  > **xNaN(`<TD>` Content)**
- Otherwise, it takes the content (it's a String because it's quoted not a Number) and converts it into a real Number.
- It returns an Array of Objects -- each object has 2 properties:

  > ```
  > object = {id: "#ID_of_<TD>", content: "String" or Number}
  > ```

The last 2 list items are extra not really required, as is the last function:

> **getCellData(Array of Objects, CellID)**

That function goes beyond the scope of question and was included for the sake of being complete.

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/* 
Pass a string that represents the targeted <table>
ex. "table" for the tag, "#tableID" or ".tableClass"
or create a reference to targeted <table>
ex. var table = document.querySelector("table');
*/
function processTable(node) {
  var table = typeof node === 'string' ? document.querySelector(node) : node;

  // Collect all rows of table
  var Rows = table.rows;

  // Get the total number of rows in table
  var rowQty = Rows.length;

  // Get the total number of cells in a row
  var rowOfCells = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  // Declare an empty Array
  var data = [];

  /*
  This for loop generates and assigns an #ID for each <tr>
  */
  for (let r = 0; r < rowQty; r++) {
    var tr = Rows[r];
    tr.id = 'row' + r;

    /*
    This for loop...
    */
    for (let c = 0; c < rowOfCells; c++) {

      // Declare an empty Object
      var obj = {};

      // Declare nfo
      var nfo;

      // Get cell 
      var td = Rows[r].cells[c];

      // Assign <td> a unique #ID
      td.id = 'cel' + r + '-' + c;

      // Create a property on Object called "id"
      obj.id = td.id;

      // Extract text from <td>
      var txt = td.textContent;

      // if content is not a number...
      if (xNaN(txt)) {

        // Set the <td> background to gold
        td.style.background = 'gold';

        // Copy the content and trim the whitespace
        nfo = txt.trim();

        // But if it is a number...
      } else {

        // ...copy the content and convert it into a real Number
        nfo = parseFloat(txt);
      }

      // Create a property on Object called "content"
      obj.content = nfo;

      // Add the Object to the Array called "data"
      data.push(obj);
    }
  }

  // The Array will be the result
  return data;
}

// This is a utility function that determines if an object is a number
function xNaN(x) {
  var n = Number(x);
  return n !== n;
};

/*
Assign a variable to the result of processTable() passing 'table' string
*/
var tableData = processTable('table');
console.log(tableData);

/*
tableData is an Array of Objects with the following pattern:

var tableData = [{id: "#ID of <TD>", content: "string or number"}, {...}, {...}];
*/

// Example: To access the data in #cel1-1:

function getCellData(arrayObj, cellID) {
  var obj = arrayObj.find(prop => prop.id === cellID);
  var idx = arrayObj.indexOf(obj);
  var val = arrayObj[idx].content;
  return `The content of td#${cellID} is: ${val}`;
}

var content = getCellData(tableData, 'cel1-1');
console.log(content);
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}


/* This is for demo purposes */

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  background: #000;
  color: lime;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row {
  background: #000;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="156" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="72" />
    <col width="49" />
    <col width="35" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" width="72" height="20">15</td>
      <td align="right" width="49">1.35</td>
      <td align="right" width="35">3.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12.0s5o9</td>
      <td align="right">123.56</td>
      <td align="right">5.15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```